# Power Query DataTable does not load

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I used Excel VBA to run a PowerQuery procedure which transforms and loads the data into a table on my Excel worksheet.

The scenario is that i have a PDF file (multiple pages) which contains some tables with data.  I recorded a macro and used it to pass variables.

So, first in my code, i call a procedure *[DisplayListTable]* to load the PDF file which gives me the name of the pages individually along with its type (whether page or table).  Then i use it to call another procedure to give me each page table's data and process the information.

I am a bit new to it and am having the following problem involving Excel VBA with PowerQuery:

Everything works fine when i step over[F8] the code or use breakpoint after executing the PowerQuery procedure.
However, when i run the code in one go[F5], nothing gets loaded into the data.  It displays as ***"ExternalData_1: Getting Data..."***

I tried to add wait, refresh, DoEvents and disable/enable events/screenupdating but nothing happens.

Could anyone help me please?

The following code is the procedure DisplayListTable:

```
    Sub DisplayListTable(v_TableName as string v_Filename as string)

    'delete preexisting queries
    on error resume next
    thisworkbook.queries(v_TableName).Delete
    on error goto 0
    
    DoEvents

    thisworkbook.activate
    thisworkbook.queries.add name:=v_TableName; formula:= _
    "let" & chr(13) & "" & chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""" & v_FileName & """), [Implementation=""1.3""])" & chr(13) & "" & chr(10) & "in" & chr(13) & "" & chr(10) & "    Source"
    thisworkbook.worksheets("LIST_OF_TABLE").select
    With activesheet.ListObjects.add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""" & v_TableName & """;Extended Properties="""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & v_TableName & "]")
        .RowNumbers = false
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = false
        .PreserveFormatting = true
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = false
        '.BackgroundQuery = true
        .BackgroundQuery = false
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = true
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = true
        .Listobject.Name = v_TableName
        .Refresh
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest adding your code (or the relevant portion of it) so that others can try to reproduce the problem or identify mistakes that your code may contain? See this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks JohnM, i have edited and provide part of my code.

Comment: I have been able to find a solution)  I have included a DoEvents before running the query and set the BackgroundQuery to false.  That worked!  Thanks again (for just viewing and closing without a reasonable explanation)

Comment: I didn't close your question ... I don't have the rep to do so and, given you added your code and further details, I don't agree with it being closed ... but there is nothing I can do about it